# Hold out for the audiobook

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Someone that I admire and that has a solid background has written in a post in relation to a book: "hold out for the audiobook - trust me"

I looked at the dictionary and it says:

- Hold out for. Continue to demand (a particular thing), refusing to accept what has been offered: he is holding out for a guaranteed 7 per cent rise.
- Hold out. British troops held out against constant attacks: resist, withstand
- Hold out. We can stay here as long as our supplies hold out: last, remain

I am confused. What does "hold out for the audiobook" mean? He recommends the audio version or not? Is that a good, precise or common aplication of that expression?

Any advice to learn phrasal verbs? for me are usually confusing and difficult to learn.

(I am from a small country in Europe and I am learning English)

Answer (score 1):

It's a recommendation that you not buy the printed book now, but wait for the audiobook.

The closest adaptation of the dictionary entries that make sense in this statement are:

1. Refuse to accept reading the book now for a the expected release of the audiobook.
2. Withstand the desire to read the print book now, considering the audiobook will be released soon.
3. We can wait here until the audiobook is released.

That audiobook version must be excellent, or much more profitable; as I can't think of a great reason to delay reading something for having someone else read it to me.

Comment: The suggestion might have been sarcastic or in jest. If the book is bad, listening to the audio book wastes less time as you can do other things while listening.

Comment: @TypeIA Possibly, but my experience is that the audiobooks take more time, and are more expensive, than a paper book.  Still, there might have been a joke in there somewhere.  I just didn't hear the statement so I can't decide if it was a sincere request to buy the audiobook, or a joke.

Comment: Right, we can't say for sure without more context, but it is a linguistic possibility.

Comment: With the context I think he is praising the book but I was not sure if he was recommending the audio or the text: https://pmarchive.com/guide_to_personal_productivity.html

Comment: @Nrc Ok, so I got curious.  Apparently there's 2 audiobooks available.  One is the "uncensored" version, which likely has obscenities and scandal that the other has had removed.  Perhaps it has material that's not even in the book.  In either case, it seems the author is sincere, he wants you to hear the uncensored version, from the author, directly.  I'm not sure if that's a great reason to hold out for the audiobook, but it might explain the writer's opinion.

Comment: @RonaldSole Thank you.  I have a skill, of misspelling.  Not the kind of skill that is useful, or desirable!

Comment: This is a very good answer.  One reason to listen to the audiobook is to hear the author read and interpret their own text. See, for example, the humorist and memoirist David Sedaris.